# Botão deslizante Ionic 3

Tags: css3, ionic, angular

Eu preciso aplicar o efeito deslizante com esses botões. Eu tenho o seguinte html:

```
<ion-row class="row-two-button">
   <ion-col class="button-group">
     <button ion-button round color="secondary" [ngClass]="{dark: travelDestinationA, light: travelDestinationB}" (click)="changeDirectionTravel()">
       <ion-icon name="md-bus"></ion-icon>
         Centro
     </button>
     <button ion-button round color="secondary" [ngClass]="{dark: travelDestinationB, light: travelDestinationA}" (click)="changeDirectionTravel()">
       <ion-icon name="md-bus"></ion-icon>
         Bairro
     </button>
   </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

[image]

Eu preciso fazer o efeito slide em scss. Estou usando Ionic 3.

Se não funcionar com o meu código html, como posso fazê-lo com outro tipo, um div ou algo como ?

Ao deslizar, também é necessário realizar uma função em angular 2 ou angular 4